# Can GENESIS simulation software be adapted to other types of tissues?

Tags: neuroscience, bioinformatics, systems-biology, modeling

GENESIS simulation software http://genesis-sim.org/ is designed for neurobiological systems and it is able to inculude in the simulation the different resolution levels - starting from the molecular interaction and ending with neuronal interaction. My question is - can GENESIS be applied to other tissues, are there efforts to do this and what kind of adaptations should be made? I guess that GENESIS is already capable to include full diversity of the molecular interaction patterns that are common to all cells. But some tuning is necessary for models at the cellular and multi-cell level? I guess that there is lack of dedicated GENESIS-level software for other tissues and systems.

Comment: Perhaps you can "switch off" the specific neuronal pathways to simulate a normal cell. However, I cannot comment much without knowing the details of the model used in the software. However, you can try this software called [virtual cell](http://vcell.org/). It also allows importing different models created by different people, from a repository.

Comment: I'm only vaguely familiar with GENESIS but can't imagine using it for non-excitable cells, since the core is the differential equations you use to simulate membrane potential. You could certainly use it for other excitable cells like immune cells to study just those properties, but if you were interested in, say, muscle, you'd probably want a whole other set of dynamics not incorporated. Maybe they've added more detailed molecular interactions since I looked last and maybe you can provide a more specific link to what you are thinking about so we don't have to dig through the docs.